# Calling variables from other classes in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that takes 3 inputs - the amount of gold in grams, silver in grams and amount of money and calculates their total worth.
In a separate class which calculates the total of all 3, how do I call the fields?

I've tried creating an object but failed, help is appreciated.
This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

       public static void main(String[] args) {



            System.out.print("------------------:");
            System.out.print("Calculator : ");
            System.out.println("--------------------");


            System.out.println("Exchange rate of gold : 165.7 RM/g");
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of Gold:  ");
            Gold goldObject = new Gold();
            goldObject.Gold1();

            System.out.println("Exchange rate of silver: 2.12 RM/g");
            System.out.println("Enter the amount of Silver:  ");
            Silver silverObject = new Silver();       
            silverObject.Silver1();

            System.out.println("Enter the amount of cash: ");
            Money moneyObject = new Money();
            moneyObject.Money1();


   }
}
```

Gold class :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gold{
     public static void Gold1() {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         double goldgram = in.nextDouble();
         double grate = 165.7;
         double gvalue = goldgram*grate;
         System.out.println("Value of gold in cash :" + gvalue);         
     }
}
```

Silver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Silver {
     public static void Silver1() {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         double silvergram = in.nextDouble();
         double srate = 2.12;
         double svalue = silvergram *srate;
         System.out.println("Value of silver in cash :" + svalue);
     }

}
```

Money class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Money {
    public static void Money1() {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         double mvalue = in.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Amount of money :" + mvalue);
     }
}
```

Total class

```
    public class total{
    public static double total1(double total) {
        ;
        total = gvalue+svalue+mvalue;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: "I've tried creating an object but failed": explain what you did and what did not work.

Comment: You need to read on [Object Oriented Programming in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use gvalue, svalue, mvalue as static member in their class. then access to member using "class name"."member name".

```
public class Money {
     public static double  mvalue;
     public static void Money1() {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     mvalue = in.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Amount of money :" + mvalue);
 }
```

}

In Total class:

```
Gold.gvalue + Silver.svalue + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways of solving your issue:

**Way 1**:

Having your static function returning double-type value and assigning them to a variable. In your case one of your static functions would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Money {
    public static double Money1() {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         double mvalue = in.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Amount of money :" + mvalue);
         return mvalue;
     }
}
```

And in your main:

```
// lines of code
// ...
double mvalue = moneyObject.Money1();
// ...
```

When you make these changes for your *gold* and *silver* classes, you should have the following variables:

- *mvalue*
- *gvalue*
- *svalue*

Then you can pass them to your *total* function after modifying its header so it accepts parameters, so it would become:

```
public static double total1(double gvalue, double svalue, double mvalue) {
        total = gvalue+svalue+mvalue;
        return total;
}
```

And call it from your main as:

```
total.total1(gvalue,svalue,mvalue);
```

However, this is not really the best way.

**Way 2**:

Having attributes attached to each class and accessing them through [*setters* and *getters*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html).

Comment: i've tried. however for some reason now after taking the 3 inputs, it repeats the third and first and then second one before showing the total.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it repeats"_ ?

Comment: as in i get the prompt to enter an input twice. First with a text, second without one. However if I enter one it will display the text its supposed to after input.

Comment: You are probably just having one extra `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a model:

```
public final class Purchase {
    private double gold;
    private double silver;
    private double money;
}
```

Define a `Calculator` clas with all calculation logic with using given `Purchase` and separate input/outpu operations with calculation operations:

```
public final class Calculator {
    private static final double GOLD_RATE = 165.7;
    private static final double SILVER_RATE = 165.7;

    public double goldValue(Purchase purchase) {
        return purchase.getGold() * GOLD_RATE;
    }

    public double silverValue(Purchase purchase) {
        return purchase.getSilver() * SILVER_RATE;
    }

    public double totalWorth(Purchase purchase) {
        return goldValue(purchase) + silverValue(purchase) + purchase.getGold();
    }

    private static Purchase createPurchase(Scanner scan) {
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase();

        System.out.print("------------------:");
        System.out.print("Calculator : ");
        System.out.println("--------------------");


        System.out.println("Exchange rate of gold : 165.7 RM/g");
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of Gold:  ");
        purchase.setGold(scan.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Exchange rate of silver: 2.12 RM/g");
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of Silver:  ");
        purchase.setSilver(scan.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of cash: ");
        purchase.setMoney(scan.nextDouble());

        return purchase;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Purchase purchase = createPurchase(new Scanner(System.in));
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        double totalWorth = calc.totalWorth(purchase);
        System.out.println("Total worth is " + totalWorth);
        // PS: using double is not correct for money!!!
    }
}
```

**ATTENTION!!!** Using `double` value in finance is **strickly prohibited**!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are getting error in this line

```
Money moneyObject = new Money();
```

This is because there is no such class named `Money`, you have only defined class `money` its case sensitive

That's one thing, second is all the variables are declared inside respective methods and thus their scope dies after the method, so after the method execution these variables won't be available.

So variables like `goldgram`, `grate`, `gvalue` etc won't be available in classes like `Calculator` and `Total`, which will also give compile time errors.

As per rates and amount of Gold/Silver you are getting individual total, then I'm wondering why you need this `Total` class.

Here is a sample about how it can be achieved through OOPs

First we define a class as `Ornament` which can represent Gold, Silver, Platinum, Diamond etc. This is only for defining the entity, no calculations needs to be kept here so that when some one reads have a clear cut idea about `Ornament`, what and all properties it have how can it be accessed.

```
class Ornament {
    private double amount;
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

See in `Ornament` we have a property `amount` which is private to class and cannot be accessed out side directly. That's why we have kept public methods to set and get `amount` (setters and getters), through this methods we can access the attribute. Like you have a lot of shirts your property(class attribute like amount), but nobody outside knows how many (private to you), but more shirts you have more you put on each day. Your behaviour is defined on your private property (behaviour is nothing but methods in Java).

So this way you have kept data of class inside the class itself which is called `Encapsulation` (private properties and public methods to access them).

Now we define classes `Gold` and `Silver` as sub classes of `Ornament`, so that they inherit the properties of `Ornament`.

```
class Gold extends Ornament {
    static double currentRate = 165.7;
}

class Silver extends Ornament {
    static double currentRate = 2.12;
}
```

The methods from `Ornament` will be inherited to both `Gold` and `Silver`. Now about the `currentRate`, a static defined for a class will be common to every object of that class. They doesn't get encapsulated inside an object. Like for every Student object of a college will have same college name, so which can be kept as `static`. The `static` variables load with their default value while class is loaded and class is loaded only once. The non-static (instance) variables will load every time when an object is created.

Now we define a class to define the business logic for calculation

```
class AmountCalculator {
    public double finalAmount(Gold gold, Silver silver) {
        double total = 0.0;
        if(gold != null) {
            total += gold.getAmount() * Gold.currentRate;
        }
        if(silver != null) {
            total += silver.getAmount() * Silver.currentRate;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

which is having a method that takes objects (instances) of `Gold` and `Silver` as arguments. If `Gold` is present take the price of gold according to the rate and amount, same for `Silver`.

Then we define a class for execution

```
public class GoldSilverRates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter amount of Gold purchased in grams : ");
        double goldInGrams = sc.nextDouble();
        Gold gold = new Gold();
        gold.setAmount(goldInGrams);

        System.out.print("Enter amount of Silver purchased in grams : ");
        double silverInGrams = sc.nextDouble();
        Silver silver = new Silver();
        silver.setAmount(silverInGrams);

        AmountCalculator calculator = new AmountCalculator();
        System.out.print("Total bill : " + calculator.finalAmount(gold, silver));
    }
}
```